# Reading response from Twitter client returns an error

Tags: api, go, twitter, response

I'm trying to make a function that calls twitter search API (using [dghubble/go-twitter](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter))

However, when I try to read the response from that API, i'm getting `http2: response body closed`

Here is my code:

```
func SearchTweets(query string) string {
    config := oauth1.NewConfig("consumer_key", "consumer_secret")
    token := oauth1.NewToken("access_token", "token_secret")
    httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)

    // Twitter client
    client := twitter.NewClient(httpClient)

    // Search Tweets
    _ , resp, err := client.Search.Tweets(&twitter.SearchTweetParams{
        Query: "elon",
        Count: 50,
    })

    
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }
    return string(body)
}
```

Comment: It's not documented, but it seems logical that it reads the body to populate the first argument that you're ignoring. Why not use that?

Comment: @Flimzy How could I use it to read response body?

Comment: I'm sure you can't.

Comment: The call ends up in [Sling.Do](https://github.com/dghubble/sling/blob/v1.3.0/sling.go#L378) eventually, which closes the request body. So yes, you cannot read it. You can probably wrap the HTTP transport and copy the response body before it's decoded, but this seems unnecessary because either the (currently discarded) search result or the [APIError](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dghubble/go-twitter@v0.0.0-20200725221434-4bc8ad7ad1b4/twitter?tab=doc#APIError) should have everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line numbers and files referenced in this response were recorded on the date of answering and are not guaranteed to be eternally correct.

From [dghubble's go-twitter search.go](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/blob/master/twitter/search.go), line 62, the `client.Search.Tweets()` function you are calling:

```
resp, err := s.sling.New().Get("tweets.json").QueryStruct(params).Receive(search, apiError)
```

Notice that it uses the `sling` package to construct and send the http request, as well as to receive and parse the http (JSON) response. The `sling` package to which it refers can be found [here](https://github.com/dghubble/sling).

Specifically, pay close attention to [sling.go](https://github.com/dghubble/sling/blob/master/sling.go). On line 366, a comment states, "Receive is shorthand for calling Request and Do."

The `Request()` function, found on line `280`, simply constructs an `*http.Request` from the `Sling` object's properties. It returns said request, as well as an error (the signature is `func (s *Sling) Request() (*http.Request, error)`)

The `Do()` function is the critical part. It performs the http request passed as the first argument, attempts to parse the (JSON) response into the second argument provided (an interface{} which should point to the object you want the response to be parsed into), and simultaneously attempts to parse any errors into the third argument provided. After all of that, it **closes the response body.** Specifically, notice lines 385 and 386:

```
// when err is nil, resp contains a non-nil resp.Body which must be closed
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

In other words, the response body is closed before it even makes it to the go-twitter `Tweets()` scope, so you're certainly not going to be able to read the body on your end. One point of these libraries, after all, is to save you the hastle of *having* to read and parse response bodies and the like.

In general, you should be able to get the information you need using the packages provided. Specifically, the `Tweets()` function has the following signature: `func (s *SearchService) Tweets(params *SearchTweetParams) (*Search, *http.Response, error)`. Notice that the first return value is of type `*Search`. This is the object read from `Receive()`, and in turn the `Do()` function. It should hold all of the information from the `*http.Response`'s body before it was closed:

```
search , resp, err := client.Search.Tweets(&twitter.SearchTweetParams{
    Query: "elon",
    Count: 50,
})
```

The `search` object is of type `*Search`, whose definition can be found [here](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/blob/master/twitter/search.go). It includes a slice of statuses (`Tweet` structures) as well as some metadata. You may also find the definition of a `Tweet` structure helpful, found [here](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/blob/7fd79e2bcc65f2e35ee1ada816481ab3e0c64d2a/twitter/statuses.go).

Lastly, if for some reason you really need to be able to handle the request body yourself, you will have to execute the request from scratch, which mostly defeats the purpose of the `go-twitter` and `sling` libraries anyways. You can build off of `sling` somewhat to construct the request, but it's not pretty (and in fact, it'd probably be cleaner to construct the request from scratch too). Nevertheless, here is an (untested) example, code written by referencing the links previously mentioned in this post, as well as [this one](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/blob/master/twitter/twitter.go):

```
func MyTweetsFunc(httpClient *http.Client, requestBuilder *sling.Sling, params *twitter.SearchTweetParams) 
{
    // Use sling's Request() to construct the request, just as Receive() does
    req, err := requestBuilder.New().Get("tweets.json").QueryStruct(params).Request()
    if err != nil {
        // handle the error
    }
    
    // Get the response through the httpClient, since a sling client would parse and close the body automatically.
    resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    
    if err != nil {
        // handle the error
    }

    // Now you can do whatever you want with resp, which is simply an *http.Response. Its body is open for reading.
}
```

And the `requestBuilder` can be constructed like so:

```
const twitterAPI = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"

requestBuilder := sling.New().Client(httpClient).Base(twitterAPI)
```

Where `httpClient` is the client you ordinarily pass into `twitter.NewClient()`